# how to substitute the variable in shell script

Tags: regex, bash, sed, grep

In the below script,I want to add the file name as prefix to each output line generated by grep.
I dont know why this is not replacing the filename with $file,I am getting the $file as the prefix.can anyone help me on this

```
function traverse() {
  for file in "$1"/*
  do
    if [ ! -d "${file}" ] ; then
      if [ ${file: -2} == ".c" ]
      then
        ./sed.sed "$file"  >  latest_log.txt #To remove all the comments
        grep -nir "$2"   latest_log.txt >> output.log #grep matched lines
        sed -i "s/^/$file/" output.log > grepoutput3.txt #prefix filename($file here)
        echo "${file} is a c file"
      fi
    else
      traverse "${file}" "$2"
    fi
  done
}

function main() {
  traverse "$1" "$2"
}

main "$1" "$2"
```

The below line should add the filename as prefix,but $file not replacing,Apart from that whole script is working fine.

```
sed -i "s/^/$file/" ex.txt > grepoutput3.txt
```

EX: search for "welcome" in all .c files of a folder.Take first_file.c is one.

## FIRST_FILE.C

welcome here

/* welcome here */

//welcome here

welcome here2

## Expected output

/DIR/FIRST_FILE.C:1: welcome here

/DIR/FIRST_FILE.C:4: welcome here2

with my script ,output is

1: welcome here

4: welcome here2

So,I am trying to prefix the file name (/DIR/FIRST_FILE.C) to each line.we can fetch that filename from $file,But sed is not interpreting it .

Answer (score 0):

Nowhere in your script is any code that creates `ex.txt`. Is that intended?
To debug this, run your script under `set -x` near the beginning.

Also worth noting: you have tagged this question "sh" (not bash) but

```
if [ ${file: -2} == ".c" ]
```

is full of nonportable bashisms: the string equality operator is `=` and the `${file: -2}` syntax is not understood by a POSIX sh. An equivalent sh code would use

```
case $file in
(*.c) ...;;
esac
```

Comment: Thaks for the reply. yes,ex.txt is not correct there,it should be output.log. My concern is how can I substitute the $file (which is .c file) in the sed command.I want to prefix that file name to the output generated by grep.

Answer (score 0):

For the filesystem traversal: **Use `find`!**

```
find FOLDER -type f -name '*.c' -exec bash yourscript.sh {} \;
```

In *yourscript.sh* you can access the filename in `$1`.

I could help further with implementing that script but it is pretty unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. With my script,I am giving a directory and string as input where all the strings present in the folder should be grepped.The exception is,we should not print the string present in the comments.For that I am traversing each file .Firstly I am removing the comments and grepping for the string.As I also need to include the file name,I am trying to use $file to add it as prefix which is failing.

Comment: It's still unclear for me. Can you edit your question and add some example data and your expected output from that?

Comment: You can just use `grep -Hn` that will print the filename and the number in front of the match.

Comment: But,we are grepping latest_log.txt ,which is just having the first_file.c lines.How can grep fetch the filename.we can have file name in $file